# C#: Why DbConnection and OracleConnection with the exact same connectionstring create two sessions on Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, connection-pooling

In my application, there are functions which use EF6 `Dbconnection` to connect to the database and run some procedure. At the same time, we have functions which use `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand` and therefore `OracleConnection`. But for both, I use the exactly same connection string.
In the [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT173) it states:

> Now, connection strings themselves must be an exact match. Keywords
> supplied in a different order for the same connection will be pooled
> separately. If a pool already exists with the requested signature, a
> connection is returned to the application from that pool.

The same statement is made in the [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling).
Therefore, I use the same connectionstring which I use for the `DbConnection`:

```
var connectionStringSource = MyConntext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString; // Exactly the connectionstring from my DbConnection
try
{
    using (var con = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(connectionStringSource))
    {
        using (Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand cmd = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand("MYSCHEMA.Get_Data", con))
        {   
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But when running this code, I can inspect the sessions on my oracle database:

```
SELECT * FROM v$session WHERE username IS NOT NULL
```

and wittness that now two sessions exist.
Why do I have two connections while they have the exact connection string? Can I prevent that?

**UPDATE:**
I know that sessions are not equal to connection pools. But according to this [book](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781590594070):

```
select s.program, s.server, p.spid server_pid, s.username from v$session s, v$process p where s.type = 'USER' and s.username != 'SYS' and p.addr(+) = s.paddr;
```

`server_pid` reflects the different connections where `v$session s` reflects different connections. And when I run this query on the oracle database I get two different `server_pid`s. One for the `DbConnection` and one for the `OracleConnection` although they have exactly the same connection string.
Thus again the question:
Why do I have two connections while they have the exact connection string? Can I prevent that?

Comment: `MyConntext.Database.Connection` is a connection object that established one session and then you created a second connection object which established another session. I'm not sure what you were expecting. Connection pooling is not session sharing.

Comment: @madreflection, please read the update in my question. I expect to have the same connection from the connection pool and not two connections for the same connection string. This is what I expect from the connection pool as this is what the connection pool is for: To prevent creating new connection (handshake task,...) when a connection with exactly same connection string exists.

Comment: The easiest inference would be that the connection strings are in fact not identical. To whit, it is not a given that connecting through EF's `DbConnection` will not end up with the connection string being parsed and reassembled, or have some keywords added (for tracking activities, for example). Try the same exercise with two `OracleConnection`s and two `DbConnection`s separately to verify pooling works on the basic level.

Comment: You're misinterpreting it entirely. Having the same connection string means the same *pool* of sessions will be used, so it will take an available session, if any, or establish a new session if it must. It doesn't mean that the same session will be reused.

Comment: Oh, and per @madreflection: a connection will not be reused at all if it can't be reused (i.e. connections are opened simultaneously) and a connection pool may keep more than one physical connection ready to reduce the overhead of creating them (the latter should be obvious to notice). So if your "at the same time" *literally* means "at the same time" (from different threads running in parallel, or from the same thread opening a new connection before the previous one has been closed), you will *always* see another connection.

Comment: @JeroenMostert,I'm not opening connections parallelly.I've checked exactly what you mentioned in your first comment and this is the reason for my confusion.I'm using the same connection string, but if I create two or more `OracleConnections`(not in parallel)just one connection and one session is made in oracle and the session is just reused.But for the same connectionstring with `DbConnection` a new session is created.If I create the same `OracleConnection` several times,this second session is used everytime.However,the`dbConnection` and`OracleConnection`have exactly the same connectionstring.

Comment: @madreflection if this is the case, that it just uses the same pool of sessions, do you know why every EF6 execution with `DbConnection` reuses one session and every `OracleCommand` with `OracleConnection` reuses another session although they have the exact connection string and are called sequentially (and not in parallel). Creating a multiple session is something the DBA want to prevent. And because my application is a desktop application with many clients, it would double the amount of session which would be a waste of resources.

Comment: That seems to confirm my theory then: one way or another, EF does not end up with the same connection string when creating an `OracleConnection`. This is why all connections you create yourself are pooled, and why all connections created from EF pool, but they don't pool together. `DbConnection` is not an EF class but a general class; try setting a breakpoint where a `DbConnection` is used, and inspect both the exact `Type` (including the assembly, don't just look at the name) and the exact `ConnectionString` the instance ends up with, compared to what you create.